# jquery traversing to next form element

Tags: jquery, dom

I have these two form elements:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="country" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Country</label>
    <div class='col-md-4'>
        <select name="countryID" id="countryID" class="form-control required populateState">    
            <option value="1"selected="selected">Australia</option><option value="2">New Zealand</option>
        </select>
     </div class='col-md-4'>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="state" class="col-sm-2 control-label">State</label>
    <div class='col-md-4'>
        <select name="stateID" id="stateID" class="form-control required stateList">
            <option value="">--</option>
            <option value="1">Australian Capital Territory</option>
            <option value="2">New South Wales</option>
            <option value="3">Northern Territory</option><option value="4">South Australia</option>
            <option value="5">Tasmania</option>
            <option value="6">Queensland</option>
            <option value="7">Victoria</option>
            <option value="8">Western Australia</option>
        </select>
    </div class='col-md-4'>
</div>
```

When #countryID is selected. I want to update #stateID by traversing up the DOM then back down to the next select field.  Here is my jQuery, which I figured should work, but doesn't for some reason. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong, or a better way I can traverse the DOM than I am doing here?

```
$(".populateState").on('change',function(){ 
        var targetSelect = $(this).closest('.form-group').next('.form-group').children('.stateList');           
        targetSelect.html('<option>HELLO</option>');
    });
```

Thanks!

Comment: Look answer it will be very simple .. but what you mean with by traversing up the DOM then back down to the next select field??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.stateList` is not a direct child of `.form-group` and children only looks for direct child elements (which would be your label or div). Use `find` instead:

```
var targetSelect = $(this).closest('.form-group').next('.form-group').find('.stateList');
```

Answer (score 0):

Tr this:

```
$(".populateState").on('change',function(){

        var targetSelect = $(this).closest('.form-group').next('.form-group').find('.stateList');

        targetSelect.append('<option>HELLO</option>');

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having an id for select, why not use it? It is way faster-

Try this--

```
$(".populateState").on('change',function(){

        var targetSelect = $("#stateID");

        targetSelect.html('<option>HELLO</option>');

    });
```

Demo-  http://jsfiddle.net/RahulB007/qcwtphd8/

Comment: Thanks Rahulb, I want to use the listener in several places, potentially multiples on the same page, therefore using class..

Answer (score 0):

You missed that the class contains several css.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(
   function() {
      $("select[class*='populateState']").on('change',
         function() { 
            var targetSelect = $(this).parent().parent().next().find("select[class*='stateList']");

            targetSelect.html('<option>HELLO</option>');
    });
   }
);
```

Thank you,